# Routing traffic in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, routes

Im fairly new with this and I need help to solve my problems. I Have 3 machine that handle a communication..

```
    - - - - - - - - - GCP - VPC - - - - - -                  External device
    |                                      |               ------------------- 
    |   VM instance A       VM instance B  |               |    machine C    |
    |     10.48.x.x   <--->  10.184.x.x   <------------->  |   192.168.x.x   |
    |   Normal machine           VPN       |               |       VPN       |
    |______________________________________|               |_________________|
```

I want to communicate from A to C through instance B, where instance A and B are in the same VPC network on Google Cloud Platform. instance B and C can communicate when the tunnel established but C cannot communicate to instance A. instance B can communicate to both machine. just like I said before, I just want to pass the traffic through instance B so instance A and C can communicate freely. I need suggestion to solve this problem, your suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify many [routes](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/routes) depending on which IP / range you want to reach.

Your next hop in your routing table may be an IP, an instance, VPN tunnel or a forwarding rule.

[image]

It is possible to have routing configured in a way you described. If you want the `instance A` to communicate with `machine C` just create a proper rule that will route all packets intended for `machine C` to go through `instance B`.

Keep in mind that you have to allow such traffic to go through so check (and create if necessary) [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls).

------- U P D A T E -----------

In your routing table select "Instance B" as the next hop (this way you don't have to [reserve internal IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address)). You only need to [reserve external static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) for your "instance B" so if it gets rebooted it's IP will stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie on GCP. That said, I am working on a requirement very similar to yours @Dhody. The previous answer is correct. You create a route as mentioned above.
I would only add some info to the answer:

- You mention that the instance B VPN is using StrongVPN so, it is not a GCP
  Cloud_VPN.
- So you have a regular Linux VM which has an internal VPC IP.
- For this scenario you need to be sure of two things:

  - The VPC IP your Instance B VM will have.
  - This can be defined at the instance creation time.
- The route destination is for the remote network at location C.

  - The next hop will be the IP of the instance B above.
  - For good measure, you could increase the priority of the route to 999 or less as the default priority for routes is 1000.

After you do that, the route will send the traffic over to your VPN at the VM B Instance.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. Glad to find another that have the same problem. Half of your answer I can understand. `The VPC IP your Instance B VM will have` Sorry, did you mean the IP range of the instance B on default VPC?

Comment: Hi! This may be a long comment. The Linux StrongVPN GW has a VPC IP, based on your region would be 10.128.X.Y. This IP is the one that has to be defined as the Next_Hop of the default gateway or specific route to create. If the Instance B IP is 10.128.0.50, a specific route will point to 192.168.0.0/16 through the next hop IP 10.128.0.50. The important part here is that the instance B internal (10.128.X.Y) IP is defined automatically. You can set it to a static on the instance configuration. Hope this helps

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer - you may find it usefull.

Answer (score -1):

You can create routing rule for this situation.

Here is "Create a route" page at VPC network pannel.

[image]

Enter the information below according to your situation.

Network : Your VPC name

Destination IP range : 192.168.x.x

next hop : Specify VPN tunnel

VPN tunnel : VM instance B

One thing to be aware of is, If you create routing rule like this, Instance A will not be able to communicate with Instance B anymore.

Traffic from Instance A will be arrive at the Instance C directly.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. My VPN setup using terminal console (Strongswan VPN), which mean I don't have any VPN network on the GCP. Can I specify the IP address for the next hop using IP private instance B?

Comment: Did you mean "Specify IP address" value at next hop? I'm not sure, but  It probably works.

Comment: You can specify next hop and put your "instance B" internal address but it's better to use "Specify an instance" option - this way you don't need to reserve the IP. But of course you can do it - no problem :)